# Is general relativity a topological theory ?

Tags: general-topology

We know that if the action of a particular theory cannot be differentiated with respect to the metric tensor , then we say that we have a topological field theory . 
In general relativity, the einstein's field equation is actually the equation of motion of einstein-hilbert action . Now , the equation of motion is achieved through variation of the action with respect to the metric tensor , and , of course the variation must have zero on the right hand side of the equation . 
Does that imply that its a topological theory ?

Comment: No, it's physics.

Comment: And physics is the natural language of mathematics. General relativity has its roots in differential geometry. Einstein didn’t know very much about differential geometry, so he asked his friend Marcel Grossmann in many things about geometry. You can find out, that both together published parts for general relativity.